# InvalidAuthenticationToken on calling Microsoft Graph Service

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am follow the tutorial that Microsoft has provided for signing a user into a desktop application using Microsoft Identity Platform and calling ASP.NET Core Web API which calls Microsoft Graph. I believe I followed all of the steps, configuring my service and client per instructions. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph

However upon trying to add  a new "to-do", I get the following error:  "Bad Request: An error occurred while calling the downstream API Code:InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: Invalid x5t claim "

The error occurs on this call:
 `User user = _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Any idea what the issue might be and how I troubleshoot?

Update: I am in the middle of troubleshooting this now with an admin. I am not getting roles back but he is and we now both agree the issue is on the azure application configuration, not the code... frustrating, but we are at least making progress.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try pasting the token into jwt.ms to decode it and inspect the claims?

Comment: I did this, and nothing looks out of the ordinary. I see my name and my email address along with other fields that I do not know the purpose of. Is there anything in particular I am looking for?

Comment: Please attaché the screenshot of decoded access token , will take a look .

Comment: Also add the screenshot of complete error .

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error due to a lack of access. Changing Delegated and Application Permission for Users solved the issue. You can try that.

Comment: I am in the middle of troubleshooting this now with an admin. I am not getting roles back but he is and we now both agree the issue is on the azure application configuration, not the code... frustrating, but we are at least making progress.